# Help in implementing of peak function in Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab, transformation

I have a function **Peak** function
[image]

I know how to implement it in time range  just need to caclulate $r$.
first I initial $x$, y with a range and meshgrid them, after it calculate $r$

```
x=-2:1/100:2;
y=-2:1/100:2;
[x,y]=meshgrid(x,y);
r=sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2);
Peak=1./r;
```

but when I want go to frequency domain, what is $f$ and how it should be initial?

appreciate any urgent help  :(